# create curl command in windows 7 command line

Tags: curl, windows-7, cmd, windows-7-x64

I downloaded the curl.exe file from the curl website and put it in my c drive. C:\curl.exe . How do I make that a shortcut in the command line?

For instance, instead of typing "C:\curl http://www.google.com", I would like to just type "curl http://www.google.com"

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a directory that will be searched for by the command processor by adding it to the PATH environment variable.

For instance:

```
C:\Windows> set PATH=%PATH%;c:\

C:\Windows> curl "http://www.google.com"
```

This will work.

You can use the command `path` in the command prompt to get the current list of directories that are in the PATH.

Of course, I don't recommend putting curl.exe at the C:\ root, but in a more secure location, like in your personal directory `C:\Users\YourName`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put `curl.exe` in a directory within your path, such as `c:\WINDOWS\` (type PATH to see all the directories in your system path) or put it in its own directory, then add that directory to your path.

For example, if you put `curl.exe` within `C:\Utils`, you can add this directory to your path by typing:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Utils
```

To make this permanent, go to `Control Panel / System and Security / System`, click on `Advanced System Settings`, click `Environment Variables`, and modify the "Path" variable under `System Variables`.  Just stick `;C:\Utils` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of adding the curl.exe file to just C:\, i added it to the C:\Windows directory

Comment: Adding it to `C:\Windows` is a bad idea.  That directory is owned by the OS.  You should really put it into a user-owned directory such as a subdirectory of your user directory `C:\Users\YourName`.